About Kratudhama and Sudhama
This chapter of Uttara Kanda from Ramayana describes Vishnu as Kratudhama and Sudhama:-

He is the Lord Hari, Narayana, the Protector of the Three Worlds. He is Ananta, Kapila, Vishnu and the highly effulgent Nrsingha; He is Kratudhama and Sudhama who bears the dreadful mace in his hands. He resembles the Twelve Adityas, He is the first Man, the primeval and excellent Purusha; He is like unto a dark blue cloud and is the first Lord of the Gods. O Long-armed One, He is encircled by flame; He is the supreme Yogi, beloved of His devotees; He projected the universe, preserves it and destroys it, assuming the form of Time endowed with great power. This Hari, bearing the discus in His hand, is the sacrifice and is worshipped in the sacrifice, He is the one great form of all the Gods, all beings, all worlds and all knowledge; He is Baladeva, O Mighty-armed One, the Slayer of Warriors; He has the eye of a hero and is the eternal Guru, the Father of the Three Worlds. All Sages, desirous of liberation, meditate on Him. He who knows Him thus, is freed from sin; he, who remembers, adores and worships Him, attains all.’

So, my question is:-
Are Kratudhama and Sudhama the names of Vishnu or his avatars? If name, is there are any reason about theme or If Avatara, Is any details about them?
